# How to display jQuery variables value in PHP on the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery and PHP code and I want to get jQuery variable value in PHP $nicks variable and then echo this $nicks value, But on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var axel = 131.5678466;
</script>

<?php
    $nicks = isset($_GET['axel']);
    echo $nicks;
?>
```

So with this the output should be 131.5678466

Comment: You can't. jQuery executes on client end where as _PHP_ on server side. You can use `$.ajax()`

Comment: Is there is anyother way to do like this and the jQuery variables axel value is not fixed that will change everytime, Because that used as dynamic not static. - Regards

Comment: how ? can you please do this & show me then so i can check that but the result must be on the same page. - Regards

Comment: redirect to the same page and append a query parament like **?axel=axel** in javascript and in php you will get the value from **$_GET** array

Comment: Or you can pass this value to the HTML to an element by using **$(element).html(axel);** Eg : **$('#elememt').html(axel);** if it is a input type element then use this **$(input).val(alex);**

Comment: @Ganesh: if you want to show small amounts of code in a comment, please use `backticks` not bold. They are usually above the Tab or below the Escape key, depending on what keyboard you have.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access straight from jquery to php because of where each of the codes execute. Jquery is a client/browser side language that only interacts with the front end. You can also think of this as anything that a user interacts with directly. PhP is a server side language that works in the backend. This usually involves the web server itself process the actions of the code where a user does not have control.

With that said you cannot access variables directly from jquery to php....but you can trick it to get what you need.

You can send a variable to a php session from jquery which would allow you to access the variable.

You can start with sending a post to a php script from jquery

**index.php**

```
<?
session_start();
?>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var axel = 131.5678466;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data: {axel: axel},
        success: function(data) {

        }
    })
})
</script>
</head>

<?php
    $nicks = $_SESSION['axel'];
    echo $nicks;
?>
```

**data.php**

In php you can get the post data and send it to a session variable like so

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['axel'] = $_POST['axel'];
?>
```

Then back to your jquery page you can access the data to php

Since you are working with sessions you have to make sure that any page where you want to access a session variable that the header of the php page has.

Comment: I am assuming you copied my code without adding the proper structure so I made the edits to exactly what you need to copy

Comment: sir can please do this in js fiddle. so i can check this. And one more thing sir the axel value will be dynamic. -Regards

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    var axel = 131.5678466;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: {text:axel},
    success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    });
});

</script>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $nicks = $_POST['text'];
    echo $nicks;
    }
?>
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: sorry sir its not working.please check again. - Regards

Comment: its working with on load page. But i need to fix it with user entered value.Like with input value.means when user enter value in the input field then it gets that input field value on the same page next after to the inpuit field You are very closer to my answer. please check & tell me . - Regards

Comment: no sir i don't want the functionality on the button click. there is a table with input fields & when i enter values in the input fields of that table then that has some calculations performed & get one result & that result is in one variable & that variable values will display on the web page as $nicks variable of php. Please check .


can you please tell me that how i pass a variable name in $nicks variable except that 131.5678466 static value so the nicks variable can get the result value all the time when it will change.


-Regards

Comment: can you provide me html or a dummy html with the same format as your html & how how you calculate these values, so that after calculation i can get it in a variable &  merge my functionlity if possible.

Comment: Try one thing: merge only this code into your existing code->   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: {text:axel},
    success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    });

Comment: after var axel = 131.5678466; & then try to echo $_POST['text'];

Comment: @user7423894: please try to avoid, at all costs, the phrase "it does not work". That does not give your helper any more information to debug what you are doing wrong. Remember that only you can see your exact use case, and you are solely responsible for implementing the advice you get here. Readers are here to help, not do it for you.