# Frontend display var data from jQuery in a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to devise a plan to display the jQuery.post `current_date`, `checkin_date` & `diff_days` from a php file in a plugin. The price of this rental item is calculated using the `bkap_get_per_night_price` Ajax code here:

```
jQuery.post("'.get_admin_url().'admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
eval(response);
var data = {
    current_date: jQuery("#wapbk_hidden_date_checkout").val(),
    checkin_date: jQuery("#wapbk_hidden_date").val(),
    attribute_selected: jQuery("#wapbk_variation_value").val(),
    currency_selected: jQuery(".wcml_currency_switcher").val(),
    block_option_price: jQuery("#block_option_price").val(),
    post_id: "'.$duplicate_of.'",
    diff_days:  jQuery("#wapbk_diff_days").val(),
    quantity: quantity_str,  
    variation_id: variation_id, 
    gf_options: gf_options,
    bundle_optional: bundle_optional,
    action: "bkap_get_per_night_price",
    product_type: "'.$product_type.'"
    '.$attribute_fields_str.' 

};
```

I found some good leads on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219456/how-to-display-jquery-variables-value-in-php-on-the-same-page#/answer-42219611), but still having trouble finding a solution. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty much universally accepted that if you're using eval you are doing something wrong, but in the context of this question, how are we to know what you're doing? The AJAX response alone should probably be json, which you can easily send from PHP, and easily use in jQuery. See PHP's function json_encode();

Comment: Appreciate your feedback Brian. I will give it my best to figure this out. Take care.